# Product of Tree Elements SMLNJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have the following `qtree` datatype:

```
datatype 'a qtree = Leaf of 'a
|   Node of 'a branches
and 'a branches = Empty
|   Branch of 'a qtree * 'a branches
```

An example tree is defined as follows:

```
val tr1 = 
Node(Branch(Leaf(2),
    Branch(Node(Branch(Leaf(6),
    Branch(Leaf(5),Empty))),
Branch(Node(Empty),Empty))))
```

Here is a visual representation of `tr1`:

```
  /|\
 / | \
2 / \
 /   \
6     5
```

I have defined the following function `tree_prod` to find the product of the values in a `qtree`:

```
fun tree_prod(Leaf(n)) = n
|   tree_prod(Empty) = 1
|   tree_prod(Node(br)) = tree_prod(br)
|   tree_prod(Branch(n, br)) = tree_prod(n) * tree_prod(br)
```

But I am receiving the following errors, which seem to occur due to a type mixup between `qtree` and `branches`:

```
stdIn:10.5-13.42 Error: parameter or result constraints of clauses don't 
agree [tycon mismatch]
  this clause:      'Z branches -> 'Y
  previous clauses:      'X qtree -> 'Y
  in declaration:
    tree_prod =
      (fn Leaf n => n
         | Empty => 1
         | Node br => tree_prod br
         | Branch (<pat>,<pat>) => tree_prod <exp> * tree_prod <exp>)
stdIn:10.5-13.42 Error: parameter or result constraints of clauses don't 
agree [tycon mismatch]
  this clause:      'Z branches -> 'Y
  previous clauses:      'X qtree -> 'Y
  in declaration:
    tree_prod =
      (fn Leaf n => n
        | Empty => 1
        | Node br => tree_prod br
        | Branch (<pat>,<pat>) => tree_prod <exp> * tree_prod <exp>)
stdIn:12.19-12.27 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: [int ty] qtree
  operand:         [int ty] branches
  in expression:
    tree_prod br
stdIn:13.24-13.42 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: [int ty] qtree
  operand:         [int ty] branches
  in expression:
    tree_prod br
```

How do I fix these errors?

Bonus: How do I implement this function using fold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have located the answer on my own. By dividing this into two separate functions, I am able to specify which types I am wanting to work with.

Here is the working solution:

```
fun tree_prod (Leaf(n)) = n
|   tree_prod (Node(br)) = branches_prod(br)
and branches_prod (Empty) = 1
|   branches_prod (Branch(n, br)) =
    tree_prod(n) * branches_prod(br)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `tree_prod` attempts to apply to both types, which won't work - you need two functions.

If it's possible for you to change the type, you can use the fact that `'a branches` is isomorphic to a list of `'a qtree` (with `Empty` as `nil` and `Branch` as `cons`).

```
datatype 'a qtree = Leaf of 'a
                  | Node of ('a qtree) list
```

and then you can fold over the branches:

```
fun tree_prod (Leaf n) = n
  | tree_prod (Node br) = List.foldl (fn (tree, acc) => tree_prod tree * acc) 1 br

val tr1 = Node [Leaf 2, Node [Leaf 6, Leaf 5], Node []]
- tree_prod tr1;
val it = 60 : int
```

If you don't want to change the type, you can write your own fold over `'a branches`, following the same form as a list-fold.
Something like this might do it:

```
fun branch_fold f x Empty = x
  | branch_fold f x (Branch t bs) = branch_fold f (f (t, x)) bs
```

and would give an almost identical "product":

```
fun tree_prod (Leaf n) = n
  | tree_prod (Node br) = branch_fold (fn (tree, acc) => tree_prod tree * acc) 1 br
```